# Changing a macro from creating a new workbook to referencing a template

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a macro that suites my needs perfectly except for one thing. Currently it creates new workbooks for me with no format. I would like to change this so that it references a template and uses that formatting.

I've been messing with the **`"Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)"`** line, but can't seem to get anything to work!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const sColumn As String = "M"

Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngFilter As Range, rngUniques As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngFilter = Range(sColumn & "1", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With rngFilter
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    Set rngUniques = Range(sColumn & "2", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


For Each cell In rngUniques
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value
    rngFilter.EntireRow.Copy
    With wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    wbDest.Sheets(1).Name = cell.Value
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbDest.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & cell.Value & " " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm-yy")
    wbDest.Close False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next cell

rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

`

Comment: are you pasting into a document that is formatted the way you want or do you need the formatting in your macro as well? wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery can help when pasting to a document with the formatting already in place.

Comment: It's creating a new document, so the destination document is not formatted. I'd like to connect it to a template so that the final product has the data of the original document in the format of a template.

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks.Add()` accepts a single argument - Template.  So create a template, save it as an .xltx file, then use that filepath to add your new workbook:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filepath As String

filepath = "C:\template.xltx"   'Or what-ever...
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add(filepath)

With wb
    '...
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

how about..

```
Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open("C:\mytemplate.xlsx")
```

Where mytemplate.xlsx is your preformatted template.  The reason I assigned it to a variable object is because it looks like you'll need to reference it in order to enter data onto the template.  If you simply trying to open a workbook, the one-liner below is acceptable..

```
Workbooks.Open("C:\mytemplate.xlsx")
```